subtitle does not appear on an html video page
i wrote this html page and i put this video from my computer and i also included English subtitles but when i choose either of the two subtitles it does not appear on the screen.
[![


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>RHoodHp</title>
        <meta name="desription" content="this is a movies streaming site">
        <h1>Movies streaming site</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video controls autoplay muted width="800" height="400">
            <source src="matrix cc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <track src="matrix.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English">
            <track src="The Matrix-English.srt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English 2">
        </video>
    </body>  
</html>



]1]1




It seems .srt tracks are not supported. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968759/does-html5-video-support-srt-texttrack The question is old, so I'm not sure. What happens if your remove it? Does the other work?

no it does not, i tried both separately

<track> only supports WebVTT. What's the content of your matrix.vtt file? What happens in your Network pane in developer tools? Is the .vtt file fetched correctly?

@htor the content of the .vtt file is subtitles for the movie, in the network pane when i turn on the subtitles with .vtt format it says blocked:origin with an error and yes i think it is fetched correctly i took it from a good source

@Wisam Please update the question with the full error message that you are getting in Network pane. It could be a CORS issue.

@htor done, pleasae check it out

You can see in the request headers from your provided screenshot that the Request URL starts with file:///F:/Movie/.... <track> doesn't work with file: but works with http: URLs. That just means you need to spin up an HTTP server to serve your files on http://localhost:8080 (or other port) and access the web page through http://localhost:8080/index.html instead. Only for local development, of course.
By using localhost URLs, all of them share the same origin (localhost) and the strict-origin-when-cross-origin Referrer Policy will not kick in.

thanks for your help brother, it worked
